# Enabling live reload with Grunt on a Vagrant-hosted project

Tags: gruntjs, vagrant

My project uses Vagrant; it's served as `https://domain.dev:8443`.

The goal is to reload the CSS into the page whenever the CSS changes, without requiring a full page reload.

I am trying to achieve this without any manual action, this means I do not want to use a browser-plugin. Everything should be able to get up and running using the task `grunt develop`.

`grunt-contrib-watch` is used to watch 3 different targets, namely `css`, `scss` and `js`. Because these tasks are concurrent, but sadly blocking, I also use `grunt-focus` to run these 3 tasks at the same time, which correctly works. Whenever changing any file that should be watched, I get a notification in my console that it changed. Awesome.

`grunt-contrib-watch` recommends `connect-livereload`, which is middleware for `grunt-contrib-connect`. This would enable me to get the desired behaviour, but I do not know how to set it up properly.

This is my Gruntfile, note that I did leave out a lot of tasks that are not related to this issue, so it will not run.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    //Load all dependencies that we need
    var ConnectLiveReload = require('connect-livereload')();

    //Load all packages that we need into Grunt
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-focus');

    //The watcher needs a clean object to store data to
    var files = Object.create(null);

    //Initialize Grunt with the options for all tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 0
            },
            develop: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [ConnectLiveReload];
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        focus: {
            develop: {}
        },

        watch: {
            scss: {
                tasks: ['build'],
                files: ['app/webroot/**/*.scss'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['app/webroot/**/*.css'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            js: {
                tasks: ['jasmine:test', 'eslint'],
                files: dictionary.javascript,
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Sets the target config for specific tasks 200ms after the last change
    var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
        var target = getTarget();
        grunt.config('eslint.target', target);
    }, 200);

    //Listen to changed files using the watcher
    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        files[filepath] = action;
        onChange();
    });

    /**
     * Gets the path from the dictionary and adds a JavaScript file selector to it.
     *
     * @method getPath
     * @param [pathkey=webroot]
     * @return {String}
     */
    function getPath(pathkey) {
        pathkey = pathkey || 'webroot';
        return (dictionary[pathkey] || pathkey) + '/*.js';
    }

    /**
     * Gets an array of the last-changed files as detected by the watcher.
     *
     * @method getTarget
     * @return {Array}
     */
    function getTarget() {
        var target = Object.keys(files);
        files = Object.create(null);
        return target;
    }

    /**
     * @task develop
     * @runs watch:css
     * @runs watch:scss
     * @runs watch:js
     */
    grunt.registerTask('develop', 'Start the automated development tasks', function() {
        grunt.task.run(['connect:develop', 'focus:develop']);
    });
};
```

`http://localhost:35729/livereload.js` is a valid file and I can visit in my browser, but the script is not being added to the page. How would I do this?

Comment: would be a dummy try and I am not exactly sure how live reload would work but can you try to make a port_forwarding on 35729 from guest to host ?

Comment: Can certainly try, may take a few days, deadline coming up for devops is on a low pitch at the moment :)